# Visual Studio built-in "XML Doc" features or free addons

Tags: visual-studio-2013, documentation, visual-studio-extensions, xml-documentation

Are there any cool added features for Visual Studio to document code faster?

I'm using Premium if that matters.

I know about the '///' auto generate XML comments above methods but is there a way to add additional information to the stub or other shortcuts to provide further documentation help on methods, classes, and/or assemblies?

I'm working to develop some development standards for my team and would like to make their lives easier if possible.

We will be using Sandcastle to generate the resulting help files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [SubMain GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) - I do not believe in 'auto-documenters', and also believe that excessive, unnecessary documentation simply adds noise.. but in my experience GhostDoc has worked well enough to save time for mismanaged projects whose leadership required "everything" to be documented.

Great for generating API docs, for example.

HTH

Comment: The main reason I want an 'auto-documenter' is to help enforce the filling out of the stubs by making it easier.  Our team develops web services that are in turn used by front end dev teams to get data feeds and provide business logic, so having efficient documentation is necessary as they won't have access to the source and all they'll have is auto generated help files generated in Sandcastle.

I've looked into GhostDoc before. I do like it, but didn't like that they add the pro version context options and just don't activate them so you don't know exactly what the free add on actually does.

Comment: "Great for generating API docs, for example"... Pretty much exactly why i'm looking into this.  Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a shot.  I feel your pain with bad projects managers with delusional requirements as well. haha.

Comment: Enforcing developers to filling out the stubs and making it easier to add (generate) them are two different things which usually play against each other. I hardly believe that a tool like GhostDoc can add meaningful descriptions; what you´ll probably get is a bunch of useless clauses which don´t add any value to the documentation.

Comment: @Matze, that's a fair assumption and mostly true. The inferences made by GhostDoc to generate comments are rarely suitable as a final product, but in terms of developer efficiency GhostDoc will add the blocks to the code, and attempt to infer a meaningful comment, which your developers can then go back and edit to become more meaningful with less time than it would take to do it all themselves. Put another way; GhostDoc cuts down on labor costs by automating the most mundane aspect of creating xml docs: adding the xml doc blocks to each type or member, however, a developer is still necessary..

Answer (score 0):

I've written an add-in, [Atomineer Pro Documentation](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) that you may wish to try. It generates and updates doc comments to keep them tidy and in sync with the code, and works hard to minimise the effort involved in documenting. It's not free, but it will save a lot of time (=money) once you start using it.